# create new portal in dnn on localhost

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke

Am having a play around with DotNetNuke 7, trying to get to grips with the basics. Have installed it succesfuly on my local machine following the tutorial online which instucts to create the a website in IIS called www.dnndev.me. This worked fine but am having difficulty creating a second protal.

Have tried every didffierent way I can find online or think of and still can't view the new portal in my browser. Can someone please provide a clear step by step instruction of how they create and view their additional portals.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DNN you can create two different types of Portals, Parent and Child.

A Parent Portal is a portal that has either its own Binding (domain) in IIS (ex: dnndev.me) or a Virtual Directory/Application in IIS (ex: dnndev.me/Portal2)

A Child Portal in DotNetNuke doesn't require IIS changes, DNN basically creates a folder (ex:dnndev.me/Child) and redirects the user around based on the portal alias.

To create a new parent portal in IIS, if working locally with IIS6 or greater, you need to add a BINDING for the portal. Using the DNNDEV.ME domain, which points to 127.0.0.1, you could create a new portal that uses a subdomain like parent.dnndev.me. To do this, in IIS add the binding for parent.dnndev.me and then when creating the Portal from the Host/Site Manage page use parent.dnndev.me as the alias/url for the portal.

The key to the whole process is adding the binding in IIS.

If you want to create an application/virtual directory, Add the application in IIS and point the application to the root of your DNN files (c:\websites\dnndev.me)